# how to setup a aiohttp https server and client?

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to learn how I might secure data from being altered after being passed over an open network between a server and a worker

in my head I was thinking that it should follow something like:

```
|server|---send_job----->|worker|
|      |<--send_results--|      |
|      |                 |      |
|      |-send_kill_req-->|      |
```

obviously I don't want someone altering my `send_job` to do something nefarious, and I don't want someone to be peeking at my results.

so I have a super simple `aiohttp` client/server setup that I'm trying to implement `ssl` into but I'm completely lost.

below is the most basic stuff I've tried, but I've also tried implementing my own ssl certificates via:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain_srv.key -out domain_srv.crt
```

along with following the [documentation](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html?highlight=ssl#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets) but I'm still never able to `get` any response at all.

How would I properly implement the `ssl_context` to get this to work?!

`server.py`

```
from aiohttp import web
import msgpack
import ssl

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
web.run_app(app, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

`client.py`
    import aiohttp
    import asyncio
    import ssl

```
async def main():
    sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://0.0.0.0:8443", ssl=sslcontext) as response:
            html = await response.read()
            print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

1. run `python3 server.py` in one window
2. run `python3 client.py` in another window

I then end up usually with something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 822, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 804, in create_connection
    sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 830, in _create_connection_transport
    yield from waiter
ConnectionResetError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 14, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "client.py", line 9, in main
    async with session.get("https://0.0.0.0:8443", ssl=sslcontext) as response:
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 843, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 366, in _request
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 445, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 757, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 879, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 862, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "/home/mEE/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 829, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl:<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7fe4800d2278> [None]
```

---

### Solution:

This was a two part problem,

1. I had no idea what I was doing with openssl, the requests library helped me figure this out!

   ```
   import requests
   requests.get("https://0.0.0.0:8443", verify="domain_srv.crt")

   SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname '0.0.0.0' doesn't match None",),))
   ```

   As it turns out, those lines I just made default when making my openssl certificates actually mattered. A slightly more correct (but probably still wrong) config similar to

   ```
   Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
   State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:.
   Locality Name (eg, city) []:.
   Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:.
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
   Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:0.0.0.0
   Email Address []:.
   ```

   led me to the result:

   ```
   import requests
   requests.get("https://0.0.0.0:8443", verify="domain_srv.crt")

   SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for 0.0.0.0 has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
   ```

   It would appear that 'subjectAltName' is something a little more difficult to add, requiring a lot more work than a simple command, you'll want to follow a guide like [this](https://gist.github.com/jchandra74/36d5f8d0e11960dd8f80260801109ab0), I will try it and see if that error goes away.
2. I think I was using `ssl.Purpose.CLIENT/SERVER_AUTH` wrongly, as @Andrej mentioned, I switched that around (as I will show below) and made a few other changes and now I am getting the correct responses.  I'll just say that, I definitely still don't understand `ssl.Purpose` but at least I have something that I can work with for now, and hopefully I'll figure out the rest in time.
   `client.py`

   ```
   import aiohttp
   import asyncio
   import ssl


   async def main():
       sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile='domain_srv.crt')
       async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
           async with session.get("https://0.0.0.0:8443/JOHNYY", ssl=sslcontext) as response:
               html = await response.read()
               print(html)

   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(main())
   ```

   `server.py`

   ```
   from aiohttp import web
   import ssl

   async def handle(request):
       name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
       text = "Hello, " + name
       return web.Response(text=text)

   app = web.Application()
   app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                   web.get('/{name}', handle)])

   ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
   ssl_context.load_cert_chain('domain_srv.crt', 'domain_srv.key')
   web.run_app(app, ssl_context=ssl_context)
   ```

   `commandline`

   ```
   >python3 server.py
   # Switch to a new window/pane
   >python3 client.py
   b'Hello, JOHNYY'
   ```

**EDIT**: 
I just wanted to post an update for anyone that's working on this type of problem.  I think that using the python cryptography library is a nicer way of generating the crt/key files so if you're interested feel free to use/modify this template (I make no promise that these are best practices):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
stuff for network security
"""

import socket
import datetime

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

import attr


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Netsec:
    hostname: str = attr.Factory(socket.gethostname)
    out_file_name: str = "domain_srv"

    def generate_netsec(self):
    # GENERATE KEY
        key = rsa.generate_private_key(
            public_exponent=65537,
            key_size=2048,
            backend=default_backend(),
        )

        with open(f"{self.out_file_name}.key", "wb") as f:
            f.write(key.private_bytes(
                encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
                encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
            ))

        subject = issuer = x509.Name([
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"CA"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Wala Wala"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"A place"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, self.hostname),
        ])

        cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
            subject
        ).issuer_name(
            issuer
        ).public_key(
            key.public_key()
        ).serial_number(
            x509.random_serial_number()
        ).not_valid_before(
            datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        ).not_valid_after(
            # Our certificate will be valid for 5 years
            datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=365*5)
        ).add_extension(
            x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
                x509.DNSName(u"localhost"),
                x509.DNSName(self.hostname),
                x509.DNSName(u"127.0.0.1")]),
            critical=False,
        # Sign our certificate with our private key
        ).sign(key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

        with open(f"{self.out_file_name}.crt", "wb") as f:
            f.write(cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

Comment: and if you wanted to allow other clients (such as a web browser) to connect to your server, how would you generate the certificates?  I assume one has to use the certificate authority for that?

Comment: Did you also need to set `ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED` on server.py to get mTLS working here?

Comment: @Mr. Buttons ^ .

Comment: I see you are doing just TLS, not mTLS or cert based auth. So you wouldn't need `ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`

Comment: @RustyShackleford -- and everyone else --  To see a better idea of how a modern org would do this you should direct yourselves to the dask/distributed repo.  It's significantly more convoluted than this tiny one-off script but it is battle tested unlike this snippet. this You can checkout this file to get started: https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/main/distributed/security.py

Based on from what I can tell they're doing things closer to what you're wanting than this snippet is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are creating the certificates but not loading them to the SSL chain. And change your  ssl_context creation from `ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH` to `ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH`:

```
from aiohttp import web
import ssl

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])


ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain('domain_srv.crt', 'domain_srv.key')

web.run_app(app, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

When you run your server, the client will print upon connection:

```
b'Hello, Anonymous'
```

Comment: How does this prevent another client from connecting to the server? The .key file is still on the server, not the client, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful for beginners like myself: If you run across the "IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for..' problem after implementing the above solution, search for how to create a self signed certificate for IP addresses with alternative names.